# Why does Killer Frost try to kill Caitlin after being freed?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the *Flash* episode "Back to Normal", why did Killer Frost try to kill Caitlin?

Comment: Um...because she's a psychotic killer who enjoys killing people?  And also because Caitlin was important to someone she hated, and she could hurt him by killing her?  But mostly because she's a psychotic killer.  Who kills people.  And enjoys it.

Answer (score 3):

Frost answers this herself mere moments after being released:

> **Killer Frost:** You know, once I saw you, I realized why Zoom didn't kill me: because I look just like you. Now he won't need me anymore.
>
> <sup>*The Flash* Season 2 Episode 19: "Back to Normal"</sup>

Killer Frost believes (probably not inaccurately) that Zoom is only keeping her alive because of his feelings for her Earth-1 doppelganger, the same way a non-supervillain might keep a framed picture of "[the one that got away](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20One%20That%20Got%20Away)". As long as he doesn't have the real thing, she's too valuable (from a sentimental standpoint) to kill.

But now he *has* the real thing, she loses her value as a memento, and her fate is likely to be the same as anyone else who betrayed Zoom. Killing Caitlin preserves her usefulness, making it more likely that Zoom will keep her alive.